# Use image style as formatter in panels pane. [D7]

Tags: panels, theming

How do you select/apply an image style to an image field that is contained in a panel (or mini-panel) pane?

I have added an image field to a panel pane, and the only option it gives me under formatter is "image." How do I get it to display all my image styles as formatters?

Comment: Good question. The only workaround solution that I can think of, is that you create a view block that contains the image and style it using views. Then add the view block to your panel.